# count down timer in php

Tags: php

I would like to ask some idea or solutions on how to make a count down timer in PHP. My page automatically refresh every minute using meta refresh so client side count down timer not needed. so server side PHP is what I am looking.

so here's the scenario.

> Last answer was 2012-01-02 10:00:00, the next answer should be 2012-01-02 10:45:00.

It means that it needs to add 45 mins from the last answer. from the current time let say for example 2012-01-02 10:05:00, so the count down timer will show 40 mins left for the next answer. if the timer becomes 0, it will show you lose. then user will answer it then another count down from the last answer added with 45 mins.

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript for Timer Display. PHP will no accomplish this since it only renders HTML. here is a great jQuery library: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to store timestamp directly of the previous answer and then add then compare it with correct time

```
$time_prev = $_some_how_from_db;
$time_now = time();
if($time_now-$time_prev>45*3600){
// do action of losing 
}
```

This was to take action when the time is OVER

Else you can keep on updating using AJAX every minute. This will avoid your refresh, which may prove bad for users convenience

Comment: i like this idea because there is an action when the time is over. but I can't make it work. can you make it show, its over if time is over otherwise show remaining time. once its over don't reset just stay in its over.. thanks

Comment: What do you wish me to show ? Making AJAX request for updating time or the action part

Comment: the timer goes to negative value after short time. is there a way not to show negative when time is over?

Comment: hmm... will be easy for us if you paste your code here. I will try to modify it as per your use

Comment: Thanks Prashant. I've fixed my code and here it is.

$added_mins = "10";
$update = strtotime('2012-01-05 16:46:40');
$target = strtotime('+' .$added_mins. 'minute', $update);
$today = time ();

$difference =($target-$today) ;
$mins =(int) ($difference/60) ;

if ($today < $target) {
    print "Event will occur in $mins minutes";
} else {
    echo "TIME IS OVER";
}

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it give me idea how to take action.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo date("i:s",strtotime("2012-01-02 10:45:00")-time())." Remaining";
```

Thought I would not recommend such solution and instead you should go with javascript..but as u said yr page is getting refresh in every minute..it's okay to use..

Comment: $lastdate= strtotime('2012-01-05 01:59:07');
$added_minutes = "45";

if (date("i:s",strtotime('+' .$added_minutes. 'minute', $lastdate)-time()) == 0) {
    echo "DUE";
} else {
    echo date("i:s",strtotime('+' .$added_minutes. 'minute',$lastdate)-time())." Mins";
}

this counter work but it reset back to 55 mins if refreshing the page. is there a way not to reset or loop, just say DUE when its due.. thanks